# Is there any way to automate encryption of files through microsoft office?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-office, encryption, microsoft-powerpoint

I've been trying to encrypt my office files (i.e., xls, xlsx, doc, docx) using Microsoft Word and Microsoft Excel or Microsoft Powerpoint. I have lots of them. I do not want to use another encryption tool, I just want to use the encryption functionality of MS Office.

The problem is it is very manual and I have to open each one of them. Is there any way to automate that encryption process?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Hi Homey, thanks for the correction. Just wondering if scripting could do the trick. However, seems that I need to do it manually.

Comment: You can probably do this using VBA. But you will need to try and do this yourself before asking for help, as we don't write scripts from scratch for you.

Comment: Hi David, I don't have a basic knowledge for VBA. I was just trying my luck if anyone in this community had already done the encryption that I was talking about.

Answer (score 0):

This article on the PPT FAQ that I maintain shows you how to do *something* to every PPT file in a given folder:

Batch: Do something to every file in a folder

http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00536_Batch-_Do_something_to_every_file_in_a_folder.htm

It calls a subroutine named MyMacro for each file it finds.
MyMacro opens the file, does stuff, saves the file, closes the file.
I've modified the sub to password protect each file before saving.
Use this version of MyMacro instead of the one on the page linked to above.

```
Sub MyMacro(strMyFile As String)
' this gets called once for each file that meets the spec you enter in  ForEachPresentation
' strMyFile is set to the file name each time

    ' Probably at a minimum, you'd want to:
    Dim oPresentation As Presentation
    Set oPresentation = Presentations.Open(strMyFile)

    With oPresentation
        ' Protect it then save it back to original folder
        ' with "Protected_" prepended to the original name
        .Password = "BEGONE!PRYING!EYES" ' or whatever you like
        .SaveAs .Path & "\" & "Protected_" & .Name
    End With

    oPresentation.Close

End Sub
```